# Evaluating Empty Strings in PHP Conditionals using JetBrain's PhpStorm

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements, phpstorm

**Context**

- I am working on a project in PHP that generates notifications for tax warrants.
- I am using PHP 7.4.x.
- I am using JetBrain's PhpStorm 2021.2.3.
- I have a C# background and am new to PHP, and don't really understand truthy/falsey.
- I have declare(strict_types = 1); enabled.

**Background**
Consider the following code:

```
public function getNotifications(string $reportName, string $appearDate = '', string $warrantNo = '', string $warrantType = '', bool $isPrinted = false,
                                 bool   $isReprint = false, bool $isTest = true): void {
    $client_type = $this -> type === 'WD';
    $pdf_obj     = $this -> portrait;

    if ($isTest) {
        $this -> getTestNotification($client_type, $pdf_obj, $reportName);
    } elseif ($isReprint) {
        $this -> getReprintNotification($client_type, $pdf_obj, $reportName, $warrantNo, $warrantType);
    } elseif ($isPrinted) {
        $this -> saveNotifications($appearDate, $reportName, $warrantNo);
    } elseif ($warrantNo === '') {
        $this -> getAllNotifications($appearDate, $client_type, $pdf_obj, $reportName, $warrantType);
    } elseif ($warrantNo !== '') {
        $this -> getSingleWarrantNotification($appearDate, $client_type, $pdf_obj, $reportName, $warrantNo, $warrantType);
    }
}
```

When called, this function takes in a handful of parameters it will pass on, as well as some bools. The bools are strictly being used as flags which are hardcoded in other parts of the code (this is incredibly old code - not my design). The logic in the function will use the bools, and one of the pieces of data to route the request to the appropriate private function.

This was my thinking when writing this function:

- I know there is only one case where $isTest would be true and doesn't depend on any other variable, so I put it first. If it's not true, we'll move on.
- I know there's only one case where $isReprint would be true and it wouldn't ever be while $isTest true, so I put it second. If it's not true, we move on.
- I know there's only one case where $printed would be true and it wouldn't ever be while $isTest or $isReprint are true, so I put it third. If it's not true, we move on.
- I know $warrantNo will be empty in one of two cases, during the run of notification report and test print. But, if it was a test print, it would have hit $isTest being true before it got here, and we know $printed is false because it didn't hit the previous elseif, so I put this fourth. If all three flags are false and warrant number is not empty, then we move on.
- Lastly, I know warrant number will have a value in several scenarios. But if it's a reprint, it will have been caught by the $isReprint condition. If it's for when $printed is true, it will have been caught by the $printed condition. And so, if we get to this condition, we know all flags are false and $warrantNo is not empty.

**The Problem**
My IDE, PhpStorm (a powerful IDE specifically built for PHP) is giving me the following warning for the last elseif where we're evaluating if $warrantNo is not empty:

> Condition is always 'true' because '$warrantNo === ''' is already 'false' at this point

I don't understand how it could be evaluating to false. The variable $warrantNo is coming directly from the function's parameter list where it's default value is empty. There is no user input in this part of the program. I know that $warrantNo will be a string, but not every scneario will call the function with a value for it, so I default it to empty.

And so, if the default is empty, then I naturally expect that the evaluation be true. In C#, this would evaluate to true. And so I thought maybe this was an issue with turthy/falsey and I did some research.

**What I've Tried**
At first, I tried different approaches. I tried

- using empty($warrantNo) and !empty($warrantNo)
- using strlen($warrantNo) === 0 and strlen($warrantNo) < 0
- changing the order of the evaluations.

All attempts still give the same warning.
I was researching PHP and watching some PHP learning series and I learned that empty strings evaluate to false. And after further searching online, I found this table from the PHP Manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php which confirms that empty strings return true with empty() and evaluate false.

**My Questions**
The ultimate question - Why am I having this problem and what are your recommendations for resolving it?

- If empty() of an empty string returns true, why would it still evaluate false? I thought PHP uses the standard logic table where if True is present, then it returns True. So if(empty('')) should return true because the conditional should be evaluating the return of empty(), not the variable being passed into empty().

Comment: `$warrantNo` is either equal to  an empty string, or it's not. If `elseif($warrantNo === '') {` is false, it's going to hit `elseif($warrantNo !== '')`. Since the previous check was false, this will obviously be true, so you can just drop the actual if check and use `else` instead. It really just a code smell warning, and while it might add a fraction of a second in an unnecessary check, it really won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your feedback. I wanted to ensure I wasn't missing something as the IDE can only provide so much feedback. I will replace the last check with an else.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually specific to PHP or loosely typed languages, it should be the same in C#. This last condition is not "wrong" but it's redundant:

```
} elseif ($warrantNo === '') {
} elseif ($warrantNo !== '') {
}
```

If `$warrantNo` doesn't match the first condition (to be an empty string) it will automatically match the second one (not to be an empty string).